# How to make a CSS Grid style that reverses columns less cluttered

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-grid

I have been playing around with CSS Grid and made a `<section>` that puts a image next to a text and reverses the column order in the `<section>` below.

When making the screen smaller I want the images to always display above the text.

I have this working now but the CSS looks really cluttered, I have been trying to make it shorter which I think should be possible with CSS Grid.

```css
.color:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}

.color:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}

section {
  background: black;
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  text-align: center;
}

.content:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.reverse>.content {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.reverse>.content:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .content {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
  }
  .content:nth-child(2) {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
  }
  .reverse>.content {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
  }
  .reverse>.content:nth-child(2) {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="content color">
    <p>
      Image
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="content color">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

</section>
<section class="reverse">
  <div class="content color">
    <p>Image</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content color">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use a plain old float or the very flexible flexbox, but knowing grid seems to be a must nowadays.
There are a few more options, this is just one using `order`.

```css
.color:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}

.color:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}

section {
  background: black;
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  section {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .reverse .color:first-child {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="content color">
    <p>
      Image
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="content color">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

</section>
<section class="reverse">
  <div class="content color">
    <p>Image</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content color">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Great this is what I was looking for! A perfect CSS Grid solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you are after but you can comma separate selectors to group rules.

```css
.color:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}

.color:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}

section {
  background: black;
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.content,
.reverse>.content:nth-child(2){
  grid-column: 1 / 2;  
}

.content {text-align: center;}

.content:nth-child(2),
.reverse>.content  {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}


.reverse>.content:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .content,
  .content:nth-child(2),
  .reverse>.content,
  .reverse>.content:nth-child(2){
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="content color">
    <p>
      Image
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="content color">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

</section>
<section class="reverse">
  <div class="content color">
    <p>Image</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content color">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot the comma seperator!